# Is it possible to boot from a dmg file directly on Macs?

Tags: boot, multi-boot

Is it possible to boot from a dmg file directly on Macs, just like the Windows setup environment, which boots from a wim file?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to properly create a bootable file is to use Disk Utility on a working Mac. You also may use Virtual box or TransMac.

Comment: Is it possible to boot from a dmg file created by Disk Utility? Here is the guide from Apple:https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372. But, if I apply this, the whole partition will be reformatted.